# C# - Netsuite fulfill salesorder line?

Tags: c#, netsuite

I am trying to update the quantity for each line item in a sales order, but I am getting stuck. I have the code below, but it is not updating the items.

```
private bool FullFillThisItem(string lineID,int qty)
{
    ItemFulfillmentItem item = new ItemFulfillmentItem();
    item.orderLineSpecified = true;
    item.orderLine = lineID;
    item.quantity = qty;
    item.quantitySpecified = true;
    WriteResponse ws = _service.add(item);
    if (ws.status.success)
        label1.text =@"Ok... something happened!";
    else
        label1.text = "Oh boy...";
};
```

At the moment, when I run the code above, I get to the success case; but when i go to the order in question through the "web gui" and look at the record, it is not updated. If i update the quantity through the "web gui" it updates correctly. :(

If anyone can lend me a hand, I will love it.
This is my 1st ever post, so hopefully I did this right. :)

Comment: You should add the output you're getting and any errors, as well as the output you expect to get. Also, The question title should be more readable, without repeating the tags as part of the title. Also, no need to add a "thank you" or that it's your first post. We know that and only adds clutter to the question. Keep it simple. The thanks comes later by accepting a correct answer.

Comment: Seems impolite to not say thank you from the start, as there are millions, if not billions of other questions that people could have chosen to click on. But I do see your point there. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code as posted won't compile. `NetSuiteService.add()` expects a `Record` object, and you've passed an `ItemFulfillmentItem` object instead.

The code below works for me.

```
ItemFulfillment itemFulfillment = new ItemFulfillment()
{
    createdFrom = new RecordRef() {  type = RecordType.salesOrder, internalId = "7795181" },
    itemList = new ItemFulfillmentItemList()
    {
        replaceAll = false,
        item = new ItemFulfillmentItem[]
        {
            new ItemFulfillmentItem()
            {
                orderLine = 1,
                orderLineSpecified = true,
                quantity = 1,
                quantitySpecified = true,
            },
        }
    },
};
```

Comment: I think I messed up on my cut & paste. :( Should I use update instead of add since I should be updating an existing item instead of adding a new item?

Comment: @YumirPatel if you are creating a new Item Fulfillment you should use `add`. If you are editing an existing Item Fulfillment then you should use `update`.

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Comment: Hi. :) How would I search for a salesorder based on tranid?